# Determine whether a list is antisymmetric

Tags: python, list, relation

I am trying to write a function so that when given a list of relations I return true or false whether it is antisymmetric or not.
if (a,b) is in the relation and (b,a) is in the relation then a has to be equal b

i.e. given [["A","A"], ["A","C"], ["A","B"], ["C","C"]] would return true

[["A","A"], ["A","D"], ["D","A"]] would return false because both [A,D] and [D,A] are in the relation but are not equal

My idea was:

```
def is_antisymmetric(relation):
    for a, b in relation:
        if (a,b) in relation and (b,a) in relation and a == b:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `>>> (1, 2) in [[1, 2]]`
`False`

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but I don't see why `[["A","A"], ["A","C"], ["A","B"], ["C","C"]] ` should return `True`. Please explain what you mean by antisymmetric...

Comment: Can you provide an example for when you expect it to return `False`?

Comment: Also why do you short circuit your loop, you will check a max of one value in the list.

Comment: Needs more `any` and `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_antisymmetric(relation):
    for a, b in relation:
        if (a,b) in relation and (b,a) in relation and a != b:
            return False
    return True

print is_antisymmetric([("A","A"), ("A","C"), ("A","B"), ("C","C")]) # True
print is_antisymmetric([("A","A"), ("A","C"), ("C","A"), ("C","C")]) # False
```

Or if you are using square bracket

```
def is_antisymmetric(relation):
    for a, b in relation:
        if [a,b] in relation and [b,a] in relation and a != b:
            return False
    return True

print is_antisymmetric([["A","A"], ["A","C"], ["A","B"], ["C","C"]]) # True
print is_antisymmetric([["A","A"], ["A","C"], ["C","A"], ["C","C"]]) # False
```

Comment: thank you so much my issue was not using square brackets

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your approach is the cost of `in` with a `list` is relatively expensive `O(n)`, which makes your current approach is `O(n^2)`. A simple and efficient `O(n)` way to do this is to add each item seen to a `set()`, `in` for a `set()` is `O(1)` e.g.:

```
def is_antisymmetric(relation):
    seen = set()
    for a, b in relation:
        if a == b:
            continue
        if (b, a) in seen:
            return False
        seen.add((a, b))
    return True

In []:
is_antisymmetric([["A","A"], ["A","C"], ["A","B"], ["C","C"]])
Out[]:
True

In []:
is_antisymmetric([["A","A"], ["A","D"], ["D","A"]])
Out[]:
False
```

Some timings...

```
import string
import itertools

rels = list(itertools.combinations(string.ascii_letters, 2))
```

Current approach (fixed by @Xin Huang):

```
In []:
%timeit is_antisymmetric_list(rels)
Out[]:
30.8 ms ± 727 µs per loop
```

Using the `set()` approach above:

```
In []:
%timeit is_antisymmetric_set(rels)
Out[]:
329 µs ± 2.99 µs per loop
```